# Compare user input against a number

Tags: python

I tried making this program.

```
print("hi! how old are you?")
name = input("enter your age: ")

eighteen = 18
if name < eighteen:
print("damn only " + name + "? you are a little baby")

if name > eighteen:
print("damn, " + name + "? you old")

if name == eighteen:
print("stop lying")
```

Put I'm getting this error whenever I input a number.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\cli.py", line 5, in <module>
if name < eighteen:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Why are you storing their age in a variable called `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that `name` is a string variable and `eighteen` is an int variable. You cannot compare these two. the best way of doing this is:

```
print("Hi! How old are you?")
age = int(input("Enter age: "))
# this will take the number and make in an integer

if age < 18: #you can use a regular number here
    print("You're too young")
else: # (if you're over 18)
    print("Bro you lyin")
```

This script works for me and I hope it works for you as well.

Edit: If you input something other than a whole number then it will give you an error

Answer (score 0):

Like @KingTasaz mentioned, `name = input("enter your age: ")` reads the input as a string so when you later use `name` in a comparison (`name < eighteen`), it throws the error you are seeing.

Their solution will throw a ValueError if the user does not input a number so you can handle that with:

```
while True:
    try:
        name = int(input("enter your age: "))
        break
    except:
        print('please enter a number')
```